# development tool to identify missed opportunity for "const"

Tags: c++, constants, code-analysis

Since C++ compilers can (usually) detect *violations* of `const`ness, are there any tools that will identify missed opportunities for declaring something as `const`?

Comment: I guess not? One rule of thumb, make everything `const` in the beginning and then start removing it as per the requirement.

Comment: Not return types though.

Answer (score 14):

gcc has -Wsuggest-attribute=[pure|const|noreturn|format], but I believe these are limited to functions and function pointers.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html